# Need a word for a paper

Tags: single-word-requests

What a word for doing something for the greater good of everyone else even if you get hurt in the process

Comment: **Jordan is a new contributor. Be nice.**

Answer (score 1):

Demonstrating "selflessness" or acting "selflessly". Noun: concern more with the needs and wishes of others than with one's own.